# parse datetime string in bigquery with custom fractional seconds format

Tags: datetime, google-bigquery

How do I get a datetime object from this string

`"2021_04_06__22_37_32_813077"`

It will be something like this, but I don't know how to handle the fractional seconds separated by an `_` in bigquery. In other languages I'd use `_%f` but that's not available in bigquery. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/format-elements#format_elements_date_time

`SELECT PARSE_DATETIME("%Y_%m_%d__%H_%M_%S", "2021_04_06__22_37_32_813077")`

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually care about the fractional seconds so this works if there is no native way to do it

`SELECT PARSE_DATETIME("%Y_%m_%d__%H_%M_%S", REGEXP_EXTRACT("2021_04_06__22_37_32_813077", r'^\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}__\d{2}_\d{2}_\d{2}'))`